# I did not get any response from the DOM xml parser in android

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I use DOM xml parser and tried to update information from file "infData.xml" that I uploaded on the server site.

When I wrote the code in a separate project was working properly; but,when i try to used code to my Main Project i dont get any response .

RootActivity.java

```
   public class RootActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_root);
    Button btn_event = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_event);
        btn_event.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RootActivity.this ,DataXml.class );
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
}
```

DataXML.java

```
public class DataXml extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(1);
            View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
            view.setBackgroundColor(0xfff00000);
        TextView name[];
        TextView Date[];
        TextView Description[];
        // Get data From XML and show data ...
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://kanoonweb.net/App_Update/infData.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
            name = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
            Date = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
            Description = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                name[i] = new TextView(this);
                Date[i] = new TextView(this);
                Description[i] = new TextView(this);
                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("name");
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();
                name[i].setText("Name = "
                        + ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                //-------------
                NodeList DateList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("date");
                Element DateElement = (Element) DateList.item(0);
                DateList = DateElement.getChildNodes();
                Date[i].setText("Date = "
                        + ((Node) DateList.item(0)).getNodeValue());
                //-------------
                NodeList desList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("description");
                Element deseElement = (Element) desList.item(0);
                desList = deseElement.getChildNodes();
                Description[i].setText("Description = "
                        + ((Node) desList.item(0)).getNodeValue()); 
                //-------------
                layout.addView(name[i]);
                layout.addView(Date[i]);
                layout.addView(Description[i]);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }
        setContentView(layout);
    }
        // End Get data From XML and show data ...
}
```

LogCat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-22 04:55:46.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1204): Process: com.example.artgallery, PID: 1204
    05-22 04:55:46.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1204): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.artgallery/com.example.artgallery.DataXml}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
    05-22 04:55:46.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
    05-22 04:55:46.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
    05-22 04:55:46.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
    05-22 04:55:46.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
    05-22 04:55:46.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
    05-22 04:55:46.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
    05-22 04:55:46.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at com.example.artgallery.RootActivity$2.onClick(RootActivity.java:38)
    05-22 04:55:46.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
    05-22 04:55:46.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
    05-22 04:55:46.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    05-22 04:55:46.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    05-22 04:55:46.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    05-22 04:55:46.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    05-22 04:55:46.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-22 04:55:46.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    05-22 04:55:46.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    05-22 04:55:46.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    05-22 04:55:46.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.artgallery"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.artgallery.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
                <activity
            android:name="com.example.artgallery.DataXml"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_data_xml" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.artgallery.RootActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_root" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.artgallery.Left"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_left" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

> I'm new to Android.

Comment: If any exception in your log cat.

Comment: @felix i get fatal exception in my logcat .

Comment: I'll ask whats already given the error "have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml"? Please paste you manifest file

Comment: its `ActivityNotFoundException`. Check whether u declared ur Activity in Manifest file or not.

Comment: You should declare all the activities in manifest file.

Comment: Yes i forgot to declare the "DataXml.java" in my  Manifest file .
i run the app and click on button , "DataXml" activity run but don't show my XML Data on Screen .

Comment: Did you get any exception in log cat like NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: @felix , no i dont get any exception like "NetworkOnMainThreadException " .

Comment: add this line in oncreate                                                                    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
   .permitAll().build();
   StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);